# Apache mod_pagespeed just on */forum/

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-pagespeed

Is it possible to configure mod_pagespeed just on a part of the website? I have a site.com/forum/ and would like to use mod_pagespeed just on the /forum/ pages.

Answer (score 1):

See https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/configuration **Location-Specific Configuration** section. It explains how you can use `.htaccess` file or `<Directory>` section in Apache's config to enable mod_pagespeed for only specific website sections.

Additionally see https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/restricting_urls how to Allow/Disallow handling of specific URLs.